# java logger does not find log file after command getRuntime().exec with nohup

Tags: java, logging, runtime, exec

I add - using java.util.logging api -

`logger.addHandler(new FileHandler(/my/example/XYLog.log, true))`

with an absolute path on linux
which then logs fine to this log file if I start my java from console on linux.
But as soon as I start same java program with getRuntime().exec (inside the same java program followed by System.exit(0)) it does not work: file is not written (but I checked that the output to console appender works fine).

As additional info, I execute my java program, both in exec and on console, with nohup XY &, syntax.

Edit: actually I found out, that two process is running in this specific case, both having a static new FileHandler(/my/example/XYLog.log, true) -> so writing to same file. Is it possible that java logging does not handle this situation? Or in general a file cannot be written if open from another process? It doesnt block though, just nothing written to the file.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found that the output is not lost, what happens is:
XYLog.log.1 is created and there it goes. Really confusing, I would have appreciated a lock exception or something instead...
It's said that java.util.logging does that to prevent concurrency issues, which can never happen in my case, I guess I can prevent this by deleting XYLog.log.lck at the start of each process.
Just tested: this solution works well:

```
public static Logger getLogger(Class c) {
.....
new File(LOCK_FILE).delete();
.....
}
```